# Contour Integral Evaluation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C = C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3$

$C_1$ = $\{z : z = t, 0 \le t \le 1\}$

$C_2$ = $\{z : z = 1 + it, 0 \le t \le 1\}$

$C_3$ = $\{z : z = 1 + e^{it} , \frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \pi\}$ .

The contour $C$ is oriented counterclockwise.

Use the definition of contour integral to calculate

1. $\int_C  3z\,\mathrm{d}z$.

Comment: What is there to set up? You already did it and you even have the different paths' parametrization. Now it's time to actually carry on the different line integrals, in my opinion.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: I mean do I add all integrals together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $3z$ is holomorphic and the path $C$ is closed, the integral is zero.

Comment: I think you are referring to Cauchy-Goursat theorem, but how is the path closed? I tried to draw the path of C1, C2, and C3 and found this:
C1 is the line along x-axis from 0 to 1 and C2 is the line segment parallel to the y-axis starting from point (0,1) to the point (1,1) and C3 is the right half circle centered at (0,1) and radius 1. I hope I am correct, and this is not a closed contour.

Comment: @Josh $C_3$ is the upper-left quarter of the circle centered at $(0,1)$. See [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot[{Re[1%2BExp[I+t]],Im[1%2BExp[I+t]]},{t,Pi%2F2,Pi}]).

Comment: @user170231 Thank you. I got it now. I had a mistake while drawing the contour C3. and the theorem used in this case is this one: The theorem is usually formulated for closed paths is: let U be an open subset of C which is simply connected, let f : U → C be a holomorphic function, and let A be a rectifiable path in U whose start point is equal to its end point. Then

$\int_A f(z) dz = 0.  correct?

Answer (score 2):

The setup is already laid out for you. You can proceed with integrating:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_C 3z\,\mathrm{d}z&=3\left\{\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}+\int_{C_3}\right\}z\,\mathrm{d}z\\[1ex]
&=3\left(\int_0^1t\,\mathrm{d}t+i\int_0^1(1+it)\,\mathrm{d}t+i\int_{\pi/2}^\pi (1+e^{it})e^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)
\end{align*}$$
and you should be getting

> $$0$$

**edit**: fixed a major error

Comment: Could you please explain why did you put "i" in front of the second and third integral, but not the first one? Also can I prove that it is equal to zero by proving that it is a closed contour using Cauchy-Goursat theorem?

Comment: @Josh In the second integral, using the parameterization $z=1+it$, the differential is $\mathrm{d}z=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[1+it]\,\mathrm{d}t=i\,\mathrm{d}t$. In the third, the same thing happens: if $z=1+e^{it}$, then $\mathrm{d}z=ie^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but how come the same is not done to the first integral? Is it not needed since it does not contain an imaginary part?

Comment: I think I got it. The first one has no i because z = t => dz = dt Thanks for all the help.